# FFMPEG sidechaincompress not working as it should?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been trying to get sidechaining to work with FFMPEG, but my complex filter skills are lacking.

I'm running two aif files into ffmpeg, hoping the voice would "duck" the background music when the voice-over is speaking. But I get an error with this command-line (on Windows, with latest FFMPEG binary):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i temp_music.aif -i temp_voice.aif \
-filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a] \
[sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.1:ratio=5[bg]; \
[bg][mix]amerge[fin‌​al]" -map [final] final.mp3
```

Everything decodes fine:

```
    ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, aiff, from 'temp_music.aif':
  Duration: 00:01:26.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, aiff, from 'temp_voice.aif':
  Duration: 00:01:26.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Output with label 'final' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

But then I receive an error:

**Output with label 'final' does not exist in any defined filter graph, 
    or was already used elsewhere.**

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Show full console output.

Comment: Adjusted the answer to reflect full console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be some type of character encoding issue.

When I execute your command as copy-pasted, I get the same error. But if I remove the final label and retype it, it works. For now, since you have only one stream to export, you can just leave it unlabelled and ffmpeg will automatically map it.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i temp_music.aif -i temp_voice.aif \
-filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a] \
[sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.1:ratio=5[bg]; \
[bg][mix]amerge" final.mp3
```

Comment: Thank you :) Indeed, seems like a character encoding problem. Is there a way to just keep the processed background music? Without the voice embedded?

Comment: Keep `[0:a][1:a]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.1:ratio=5` and remove asplit, amerge.